# v2 Wix React-native-navigation: how to actually implement side Menu with bottomTabs?

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-navigation, wix-react-native-navigation, react-native-navigation-v2

I am having a bit of trouble implementing the sideMenu to the following code: (see the startTabs).

I call this after "login" is clicked on my root screen. The root screen looks like the following:

```js
Navigation.setRoot({
  root: {
    stack: {
      children: [{
        component: {
          name: "navigation.playground.WelcomeScreen",
          passProps: {
            text: "stack with one child"
          },
          alignment: "center",
          options: {
            topBar: {
              visible: true,
              title: {
                text: "main screen"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }]
    }
  }
});
```

```js
const startTabs = () => {
  Promise.all([
    Icon.getImageSource("md-map", 30),
    Icon.getImageSource("ios-share-alt", 30)
  ]).then(sources => {
    Navigation.setRoot({
      root: {
        bottomTabs: {
          children: [{
              stack: {
                children: [{
                    component: {
                      name: "navigation.playground.FindPlaceScreen",
                      options: {
                        bottomTab: {
                          text: "Find Place",
                          icon: sources[0]
                        },
                        topBar: {
                          visible: true,
                          title: {
                            text: "Find Place"
                          }
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  }

                ]
              }
            },
            {
              stack: {
                children: [{
                  component: {
                    name: "navigation.playground.SharePlaceScreen",
                    options: {
                      bottomTab: {
                        text: "Share Place",
                        icon: sources[1]
                      },
                      topBar: {
                        // visible: true,
                        title: {
                          text: "Share Place"
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }]
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    });
  });
};
```

Now in order for me to implement sideMenu after login, Would I implement it in the "startTabs"? or elsewhere?

Answer (score 0):

Solved this. Sorry I am a new programmer, so I had a spelling mistake in my sideDrawer component where "render" was spelled "redner". Took me the longest time to figure this out!!!

Otherwise the code I pasted in initial question is correct (for anyone who looks at this for reference). Thanks!